# Are there reliable studies on the viability of the SARS-CoV-2 virus with respect to temperature?

Tags: covid-19, sars-cov-2

There have been "suggestions" (facebook, media etc) that the novel coronavirus is heat sensitive. Specifically that the virus is "killed" or impotent when subjected to temperature of 77F.

Are there any peer-reviewed studies that would support such a contention?

More broadly, are there any peer-reviewed studies on the viability of the virus in other naturally occurring circumstances?

(As I am not a medical professional or researcher, I'm a bit lost on how to do my own research to find appropriate and reliable information on this - I'm not even sure that I'm using the appropriate terminology. This is why I've come to this site: for guidance on how to get the information )

Comment: There are confirmed COVID-19 cases in Australia, South Africa, and South America, where it's summer, along with most of the tropics. I think that blows the 77F theory right out of the water.

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, that  follows intuitively, but what i'm looking for is clinical research that will illustrate the lifetime of the virus subjected to temperature as well as other environmental conditions. (as an example, will laundry detergent and washing in cool water kill the virus - this is an important factor in caring for a home bound infected person - and if the laundry water needs to be hot - just how hot.

Comment: You might want to do some more research on this. Assuming you use soap in your laundry, then it won't matter much what the temperature is. Soap breaks down the lipid shell of viruses like corona, and that destroys the virus.

Comment: @CareyGregory  thank you, that's the TYPE of information that I'm looking for, information that seems to have a scientific basis. Is this (lipid shell breakdown) something that you just know because of training or education, or something you were able to discover through researching clinical work of other scientists?   Would you advise me to google "coronavirus breakdown" or lipid shell breakdown" or do you have some other guidance to help me in my research for literature?

Comment: Honestly, I would start at the beginning with something like this https://www.nytimes.com/2020/03/13/health/soap-coronavirus-handwashing-germs.html

Comment: The sars-cov-2 arose from bat populations originally. Bats basically fly with a fever due to their high metabolic rates so it is expected that the virus is not temperature sensitive.

Comment: @CareyGregory great article, Thanks. I'm going to broaden the scope with another question about the peer-review process as it applies to medical/virus research investigations.

Comment: @CareyGregory It's about 85F where I live today and clear skies.  I wondered about just leaving the stuff I bought in the trunk of the car for a few hours in direct sunlight.  It would be nice if I could just bake all that stuff and feel good that something exposed at x degrees for y minutes kills it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:
According to:[Lancet April 2 2020](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lanmic/article/PIIS2666-5247(20)30003-3/fulltext)

The concentration of SARS-COV-2 decayed thusly:[image]

To my non-professional eye it appears that at 72F the concentration of SARS-COV-2 decayed by (approximately) 50% after 72 hours.

When the same experiment was carried at at 99F the concentration decayed by 50% in 24 hours.

The same experiment when carried out at 133 F, the concentration decayed by 50% in 10 minutes.

The layperson's conclusion: Extraordinary heating conditions (greater than 100 F) will be required to decay the virus in a reasonable time period (less than 24 hours).

Answer (score 3):

Here are studies on viability at different temperature for similar viruses

[image]

https://www.journalofhospitalinfection.com/article/S0195-6701(20)30046-3/fulltext

Answer (score 2):

**Casanova LM et al. 2010, "Effects of air temperature and relative humidity on coronavirus survival on surfaces."**
    This study on other similar viruses -- transmissible gastroenteritis virus and mouse hepatitis virus -- showed that those viruses persisted for as long as 28 days at 4 degrees C, and stayed activated at low humidity (20% RH).  But inactivation was more rapid at warmer temperature, 20 deg C.  At 40 degrees, both viurses were inactivated more rapidly.  Humidity was different, as there was greater survival at high (80%).
    The Abstract: Assessment of the risks posed by severe acute respiratory syndrome (SARS) coronavirus (SARS-CoV) on surfaces requires data on survival of this virus on environmental surfaces and on how survival is affected by environmental variables, such as air temperature (AT) and relative humidity (RH). The use of surrogate viruses has the potential to overcome the challenges of working with SARS-CoV and to increase the available data on coronavirus survival on surfaces. Two potential surrogates were evaluated in this study; transmissible gastroenteritis virus (TGEV) and mouse hepatitis virus (MHV) were used to determine effects of AT and RH on the survival of coronaviruses on stainless steel. At 4 degrees C, infectious virus persisted for as long as 28 days, and the lowest level of inactivation occurred at 20% RH. Inactivation was more rapid at 20 degrees C than at 4 degrees C at all humidity levels; the viruses persisted for 5 to 28 days, and the slowest inactivation occurred at low RH. Both viruses were inactivated more rapidly at 40 degrees C than at 20 degrees C. The relationship between inactivation and RH was not monotonic, and there was greater survival or a greater protective effect at low RH (20%) and high RH (80%) than at moderate RH (50%). There was also evidence of an interaction between AT and RH. The results show that when high numbers of viruses are deposited, TGEV and MHV may survive for days on surfaces at ATs and RHs typical of indoor environments. TGEV and MHV could serve as conservative surrogates for modeling exposure, the risk of transmission, and control measures for pathogenic enveloped viruses, such as SARS-CoV and influenza virus, on health care surfaces.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20228108

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness:
**Aerosol and Surface Stability of SARS-CoV-2 as Compared with SARS-CoV-1** (dated March 17 2020) from 
[New England Journal of Medicine](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMc2004973)

Begins:

> A novel human coronavirus that is now named severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2 (SARS-CoV-2) (formerly called HCoV-19) emerged in Wuhan, China, in late 2019 and is now causing a pandemic.1 We analyzed the aerosol and surface stability of SARS-CoV-2 and compared it with SARS-CoV-1, the most closely related human coronavirus.2
>
> We evaluated the stability of SARS-CoV-2 and SARS-CoV-1 in aerosols and on various surfaces